# Blazor can't load image from class library at publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor component libary that has a PDFGenerator component. I consume this library by Blazor server application, I have to send path of image to add it in the PDF. In development stage it works fine but after deploying to test server I get an error becuase of the path. 
**Server application:** 
`var Path="..\\BlazorUI\\Blazor.Components\\wwwroot\\Images\\Logo.png"` 
**Blazor component libaray** 
`Image image = section.Headers.Primary.AddImage(ImageSource.FromFile(path));` 
**Error** 
`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Webservice\BlazorUI\Blazor.Components\wwwroot\Images\Logo.png` 
**The path of the Images folder in the server:** 
`C:\Webservice\application\wwwroot\_content\Blazor.Components\Images` 
**My question:** 
How can I use dynamic path to work in development stage and also in the test server? 
Thanks

Comment: I see `Environment.CurrentDirectory() used quite a bit when accessing appsettings files, perhaps you could start with that and then traverse your filesystem from there.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The paths are wrong. Content paths are **all** relative to `wwwroot`, not the developer machine's project path. Everything outside this is code compiled into a `dll`. At the very least try with `var Path="_content\\Blazor.Components\\Images\\Logo.png"`

Comment: If the path is included in the component library you be able to use a shorter path inside the library itself, as the root will be relative to the component's folder, eg `Images/Logo.png`. I haven't tried this lately though

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos.
 `_content\\Blazor.Components\\Images\\Logo.png`, this will work in publishing but not on development. This means that I cannot dev and publish my project and reference the same files using the same request path, I need a dynamic way

Comment: Maybe this would work: `System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.WebRootPath, @"Images/Logo.png")`

Comment: Hi, you can try to use `IWebHostEnvironment` to find the dynamic path .

Comment: It will not work because in development mode It will return path to wwwroot of application project and not wwwroot of the class library

Answer (score 0):

I made a temporary  solution:

```
var path = "";
var publishFolder = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\_content\\Blazor.Components");
 //Publish mode
 if (Directory.Exists(publishFolder))
 {
      path = Path.Combine(publishFolder, restPath);
 }
 //development mode
 else
 {
     path = Path.Combine("..\\BlazorUI\\Blazor.Components\\wwwroot\\", restPath);
 }
 Image image = section.Footers.Primary.AddImage(ImageSource.FromFile(path));
```

**Note** 
After publishing: this path `_content/Blazor.Components/Images` has been created inside `wwwroot` of the main application folder in the server.